# How to retain line breaks when textarea converted to php mail

Tags: php, email, textarea, nl2br

I've seen this question posed numerous times here, with most answers the same: use nl2br() function.  Which is great, as far as it goes...
Anyway, first the form which sends contents as $message:

```
<textarea name=aMessage rows="46" cols="60" tabindex=5 value=<?php $message; ?> >
Honourable Jane Doe,
Minister of Environment

Sincerely,

</textarea>
```

Then the conversion:

```
$message = nl2br(htmlentities($message));
echo $message;
```

NOTE: with that use of nl2br(), the echo that follows shows the contents with line breaks properly inserted.  Great!  Then that is handed over to the send_mail() function, which produces a formatted email (tidy boxes etc.) - which looks like:

```
function send_email($name,$mail,$message) {
$to = "my@email.net";
$subject = "Testing - Public Input";
$body = "
<html><head>
</head><body>Testing - Public Input<br><br>
<table>
<tr><th>Name:</th><th>Email Address:</th></tr>
<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$mail."</td></tr>
<tr><th>FEEDBACK:</th></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='padding:10px;display:block'>".$message."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: thor@gator4116.hostgator.com\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```

At which point, an email is produced with NO line breaks.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function send_email($name,$mail,$message) {
$to = "my@email.net";
$subject = "Testing - Public Input";
$body = <<< EOF
<html><head>
</head><body>Testing - Public Input<br><br>
<table>
<tr><th>Name:</th><th>Email Address:</th></tr>
<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$mail."</td></tr>
<tr><th>FEEDBACK:</th></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='padding:10px;display:block'>".$message."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
EOF;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: thor@gator4116.hostgator.com\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```